# C# Sequence Contains No Elements - Load or Add?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am receiving the following error in my C# WPF application:

```
StackTrace  "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Configure>b__3(Tuple`2 pm)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Load(IQueryable source)
   at Insurance_MidAm_Interface.MainWindow.Window_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\\Users\\Khandokar\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Insurance MidAm Interface\\Insurance MidAm Interface\\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 80"   string
```

This is the code that throws the Exception:

```
     System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource employeeViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("employeeViewSource")));
   try { dbContext.employees.Load();  //// Line 80    

        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            Console.Write(EX.InnerException);
        }
employeeViewSource.Source = dbContext.employees.ToList();

    }
```

I have tried virtually everything I can think of. I have added test data to the database and even placed both employeeViewSource.Source = dbContext.employees.ToList() and  dbContext.employees.Load(); in the Try/Catch block. Whenever I do the latter, the application will load, but whenever I attempt to add an entity, I get the same error. I have looked around, and most of the solutions involve not making a call to Single (instead using SingleOrDefault). However, I am not explicitly make a call to "Single" (though from the Stack Trace, it is apparently getting called anyway).

What might the issue be?

Thanks so much.

Employee model

```
public partial class employee
{
    public employee()
    {
        beneficiaries = new HashSet<beneficiary>();
        children = new HashSet<child>();
        reports = new HashSet<report>();
        spouses = new HashSet<spouse>();
        visions = new HashSet<vision>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(12)]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string year { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string first { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string last { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    [Required]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string location { get; set; }

    public DateTime birth { get; set; }

    private string _displayDate;
    public string displayDate
    {
        get
        {
            _displayDate = this.birth.ToShortDateString();
            return _displayDate;
        }
    }


    private string displaySSN;
    public string SSN
    {
        get
        {
            ssnDecrypter decrypter = new ssnDecrypter();
            decrypter.cryptString = this.ssn;
            byte[] key = decrypter.hexToBin(MainWindow.KEY);
            byte[] ssn = decrypter.hexToBin(decrypter.getSSN());
            byte[] iv = decrypter.hexToBin(decrypter.getIV());
            displaySSN = decrypter.decrypter(ssn, key, iv);
            return displaySSN;


        }
    }


    [StringLength(50)]
    public string decision { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string dependents { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string vision { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ssn { get; set; }

    public bool filed { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<beneficiary> beneficiaries { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<child> children { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<report> reports { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<spouse> spouses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<vision> visions { get; set; }
}
}
```

insuranceModel (dbContext)

```
public partial class insuranceModel : DbContext
{
    public insuranceModel()
        : base("name=insuranceModel2")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<action> actions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<beneficiary> beneficiaries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<child> children { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<employee> employees { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<report> reports { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<spouse> spouses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<vision> visions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<action>()
            .HasMany(e => e.reports)
            .WithRequired(e => e.action)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.decision)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<beneficiary>()
            .Property(e => e.year)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<beneficiary>()
            .Property(e => e.ssn)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<beneficiary>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<beneficiary>()
            .Property(e => e.address)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<child>()
            .Property(e => e.year)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<child>()
            .Property(e => e.ssn)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .Property(e => e.year)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .Property(e => e.address)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .Property(e => e.location)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .Property(e => e.ssn)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.beneficiaries)
            .WithRequired(e => e.employee)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.empId, e.year })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.children)
            .WithRequired(e => e.employee)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.empId, e.year })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.reports)
            .WithRequired(e => e.employee)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.empId, e.year })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.spouses)
            .WithRequired(e => e.employee)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.empId, e.year })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.visions)
            .WithRequired(e => e.employee)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.empId, e.year })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<report>()
            .Property(e => e.year)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<spouse>()
            .Property(e => e.year)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<spouse>()
            .Property(e => e.ssn)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<spouse>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<spouse>()
            .Property(e => e.address)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<spouse>()
            .Property(e => e.gender)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<spouse>()
            .Property(e => e.isEmployed)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<vision>()
            .Property(e => e.year)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<vision>()
            .Property(e => e.ssn)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<vision>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<vision>()
            .Property(e => e.gender)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post employee data model & dataContext

Comment: Certainly. The post has been edited.

Comment: Can you add  [NotMapped] attribute to readonly properties

Comment: Your catch block is odd, too.  Many exceptions don't have an `InnerException` so you may be missing valuable diagnostic information. I would just use `Console.Write(EX)` so that you get all information necessary to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I think problem is 
        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        [Required]
        public string address { get; set; } 
        
        You can check following page for supported data types.
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382832(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName this method gets data type for property and selects single datatype. means Column(TypeName = "text") type is not found Single() throws excaptions if there's not record.

Comment: You are absolutely right - the problem was related to the data type attributes. Again thanks so much!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx This is SQL Server Data Types.

Comment: @KellyMarchewa Can you say which one/s was/were the problem?

Comment: It is a bit complicated, as I was using GIT for version control and had some extra DataAttributes specified in my "main/working" branch, but honestly, I think it was both a "Date" type I had specified (not shown) and "Text". The reason I say this, is because the issue occurred when I switched from a local database to an older, full version of SQL Server, and, while creating the database I had received an error about the later not supporting the "Date" type (just DateTime). However, I believe I honestly just removed all "TypeName" and similar declaration, and it worked.

Comment: If you're using Db first you can use https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Reviews/2 to generate poco classess & DbContext. This way you'll not have issue.